# Sql query data exist in all

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have user and role table. User have multiple role....

```
user table - id, username

manageroles table - id, user_id, role_id

roles table - id, rolename
```

suppose user a have role_id = 1 and 2

suppose user b have role_id = 2 and 3

test case-

```
1- want user of roleid 2-----output- a,b
2- want user of roleid 1,2-----output- a
3- want user of roleid 2,3-----output- b
```

please suggest single sql query to get this kind of output. I am using cakephp 1.3 and mysql 5.6.

Comment: And you save data as comma separated ?

Comment: Use in clause of mysql.

Comment: it is just example....column is user_id and role_id...for one user there is multiple entry...

Comment: You'd better show us (sample) table data, in the right column format.

Answer (score 1):

Since you store data in one to many relation the first query will be simple

```
select * from table_name 
where role_id = 2;
```

For 1,2

```
select user_id from table_name 
where role_id in (1,2)
group by user_id having count(Distinct role_id) = 2 ;
```

For 2,3

```
select user_id from table_name 
where role_id in (2,3)
group by user_id having count(Distinct role_id) = 2 ;
```

Comment: ya it will solve my issue..but if there is multiple entry in that case..multiple entry means is same row inserted twice by mistake....it may return wrong output...

Comment: Yes if there is a multiple entry i.e. more than 2 then the condition would be `having count(distinct role_id) = 2`, but if you have a different roleid than that in the in clause then you have use `>=2`